# Copy Image from pdf or uiwebview in IOS?

Tags: ios, image, uiimageview, uipasteboard

how can i get image from UIPasteboard after the user click copy actually i can get Nsdata from UIPasteboard but i think it needs specific coding to be assigned to uiimageview how can i do this ?  thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = // however you obtain the data
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Even better:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] image];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```